# creating an array in a for loop in python, but data not getting copied correctly

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, average, jupyter-notebook

So I am trying to create an array in a for loop with a specific shape. I'm starting with a 3D array with shape `(14616, 145, 192)`, then taking the average of the data, and putting it into an array. I'm expecting to get a 1D array with 14616 values in it using the following code:

`data = np.zeros(14616)`

`for x in pr1:
     data = np.average(x)`

When written like this the new array looks like this:

`print data.shape
print data
()
2.37915e-05`

For whatever reason, when written like this it is only taking the last average value that was calculated and putting that into the array, when I want all of them. I've fiddled with a few different things, but nothing seems to work and I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, because you are simply assigning the result of `np.average(x)` to `data`, and discarding your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply assigning the result of your `mean` calculation to `data`. So, if I have `x = [1,2,3]`, and then I do `x = 4`, then **`x == 4`** and the original list is discarded.

So, when you say:

> For whatever reason, when written like this it is only taking the last
>   average value that was calculated and putting that into the array...

That is wrong. It isn't *doing anything to the array*, it is reassigning `data` to the value of `np.average(x)` on each iteration of the loop, thus, `data` will be whatever `np.average(x)` is on the last iteration.

Anyway, I would dispense with your looping approach altogether, instead, use the built-in `np.mean`, either the function or method. So, using a toy-example:

```
>>> pr1 = np.random.randint(-5, 20, (8, 2, 3))
>>> pr1
array([[[16,  4, -5],
        [ 5, 16,  7]],

       [[13, 16, -3],
        [12, 10, 14]],

       [[13, -4, 12],
        [-5, 12,  1]],

       [[ 9, -1, -3],
        [14, 11, 15]],

       [[12, 17, 14],
        [16,  5,  2]],

       [[-1, 13, -2],
        [ 4,  9, 11]],

       [[12,  8, 19],
        [ 4,  9, -2]],

       [[-4, -2,  1],
        [ 8, -1, 14]]])
>>>
```

Then simply:

```
>>> data = pr1.mean(axis=(1,2))
>>> data
array([  7.16666667,  10.33333333,   4.83333333,   7.5       ,
        11.        ,   5.66666667,   8.33333333,   2.66666667])
>>> data.shape
(8,)
>>> pr1.shape
(8, 2, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: @AlexMorrison to get the most out of `numpy`, try to learn to use the built-in vectorized methods. They are implemented as C-extensions and are compiled and much, *much* faster than plain python loops.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop `for x in pr1:`, you keep assigning average of x to `data`, hence finally `data` only takes 1 value.

You can achieve your target using list comprehension as well:

```
>>> data = np.random.rand(146,15,19)
>>> data = np.array([np.average(j) for j in data])
>>> data.shape
(146,)
```

Comment: This method also worked, but for some reason took a really long time to run.